# How can I export all my named exports in a default object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I can do:

```
import fs from 'fs'
//now use fs normally
fs.open('file')
```

But I can't do the same with the modules I write:

```
import myModule from 'myModule'
       ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'myModule' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

I am forced to do:

```
import * as myModule from 'myModule'
//now use myModule normally
myModule.do_something()
```

Is it possible to automatically export all the named exports in the default one so that it's not required to import `* as`?

Comment: `export default { named, things }`?

Comment: Doesn’t the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) help?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: do I have to manually list every named export one by one? Isn't it possible to automatically export them all in the default object?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot export multiple `default exports`. use `named exports` instead.

example here is the exported modules from a file named `Test.js`:

```
export const namedVar = "named1";

export const do_something = () => console.log("do something");
```

you can use it this way:

```
import { namedVar, do_something } from './Test'

console.log(namedVar);
console.log(do_something());
```